# Is $C^1[0,1]$ a measurable subset of $C[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, continuity, borel-sets

I am wondering whether $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, the set of continuously differentiable functions, is an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(C[0,1],\|\cdot \|_\infty)$. As far as I know, it is neither open nor closed, but I feel like it would be natural for this to be true.

If this is not the case, what about the set of (not necessarily continuously) differentiable functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $T: \mathbb  R \times C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ by $T(c,f)(x)=c+\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$. Then $T$ is continuous, hence Borel mesurable. Also, $T$ is injective. By Theorem 8.3.7 of Cohn's Measure Theory (see p. 276) it follows that the image of $T$ is  Borel set. But the image is exactly $C^{1}[0,1]$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quick answer!